# html, css and php website container div not containing

Tags: php, css, html

I am stuck and I am desperate. Here is the problem:

I have a div "container" that includes all the other divs.
But somehow the div ends where the first php statement is! Magic I say.
I want the container div to hold the whole page, but it reaches the first php statement (that includes the code from another file into the page) and ends. I can't find the reason.

Code.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>{subTITLE}<?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="description" content="{subDESCRIPTION}<?php echo DESCRIPTION; ?>">
<meta http-equiv="keywords" content="<?php echo KEYWORDS; ?>">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABSWEBTPLPATH; ?>main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="superbar">
                    <div class="menuSearch">
                    <span>
                        <?php ShowSearchForm(); ?>
                    </span>
                    </div>

</div>
<div class="container">


        <?php include(TPLPATH.'header.php'); ?>

<br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="content">
            <div class="contentLeft">
                <div class="cLhead">
                    <h4>
                    Categories
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="categories">
                    <?php ShowMenu(); ?>    

                </ul>
            </div>
            <span class="contentRight">
                <?php ListGoods(); ?>
            </span> 
    </div>



    <?php include(TPLPATH.'footer.php'); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP of header.php

```
    <div class="header-container">
    <div class="wrapper">

    </div>
        <div id="header_top_right">
        <div class="btn1">
            <span class="menuPokupki"><div class="description"><a href="http://www.oplata.info" target="_blank">Мои покупки</a></div><div class="descriptionSub"><nobr>история покупок</nobr></div></span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn2">
            <span>
            <a href="<?php echo ABSWEBPATH; ?>" title="Мой магазин"><h5 >Мой&nbsp;магазин</h5></a>
            </span>
        </div>

        <form action="<?php echo ABSWEBPATH; ?>ch_rt.php" method="post">
        <span class="cnt">
            Валюта:
            <select name="rt" class="sorting">
            <?php
            session_start();

            if(isset($_SESSION["rt"]) && !empty($_SESSION["rt"])) {
            if($_SESSION["rt"] == "wmr" or $_SESSION["rt"] != "wmz" or $_SESSION["rt"] != "wme" or $_SESSION["rt"] != "wmu") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmr\" selected=\"selected\">руб. (RUR)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmr\">руб. (RUR)</option>\r\n";}

            if($_SESSION["rt"] == "wmz") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmz\" selected=\"selected\">$ (USD)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmz\">$ (USD)</option>\r\n";}

            if($_SESSION["rt"] == "wme") {
            echo "<option value=\"wme\" selected=\"selected\">&euro; (EUR)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wme\">&euro; (EUR)</option>\r\n";}

            if($_SESSION["rt"] == "wmu") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmu\" selected=\"selected\">грн. (UAH)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmu\">грн. (UAH)</option>\r\n";} }
            else {

            if(isset($default_rt) && !empty($default_rt)) {
            if($default_rt == "wmr" or $default_rt != "wmz" or $default_rt != "wme" or $default_rt != "wmu") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmr\" selected=\"selected\">руб. (RUR)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmr\">руб. (RUR)</option>\r\n";}

            if($default_rt == "wmz") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmz\" selected=\"selected\">$ (USD)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmz\">$ (USD)</option>\r\n";}

            if($default_rt == "wme") {
            echo "<option value=\"wme\" selected=\"selected\">&euro; (EUR)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wme\">&euro; (EUR)</option>\r\n";}

            if($default_rt == "wmu") {
            echo "<option value=\"wmu\" selected=\"selected\">грн. (UAH)</option>\r\n"; }
            else {echo "<option value=\"wmu\">грн. (UAH)</option>\r\n";} }

            else {
            echo "<option value=\"wmr\" selected=\"selected\">руб. (RUR)</option>
            <option value=\"wmz\">$ (USD)</option>
            <option value=\"wme\">&euro; (EUR)</option>
            <option value=\"wmu\">грн. (UAH)</option>\r\n"; } }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Установить" class="button" />
            </form></span></div>


            </div>

        <div class="subheader">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu1" noWrap><a href="about.php">О магазине</a></li>
            <li class="menu1" noWrap><a href="pay.php">Способы оплаты</a></li>
            <li class="menu1" noWrap><a href="contact.php">Контакты</a></li>
            <span class="filter">
                <span class="sortingTitle">Сортировка:</span>
                <span class="sortingSelect">
                <?php GoodsSort(); ?>
                </span>

        </span>
        </ul>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS has 500 lines so I uploaded it to pastebin 
sorry for terrible crap code. I have to urgently edit someone else's and I already hate him

> http://pastebin.com/6b5UC9mj

Comment: Look in your Apache error log.

Comment: incorrect html structure of your header.php Check your starting and closing div tags. There are 10 opened tags in header, and only 8 closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your span is closed outside the form. Your current structure is :

```
<form action="<?php echo ABSWEBPATH; ?>ch_rt.php" method="post">
   <span class="cnt">
      ....
   </form>
 </span>
```

Must be:

```
<form action="<?php echo ABSWEBPATH; ?>ch_rt.php" method="post">
   <span class="cnt">
      ....
    </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Too many closing divs in header.php

Take the last one out